# couldn't downgrade tensorflow in colab (just version 2 is available)

Tags: google-colaboratory, downgrade, tensorflow1.15

Colab does not allow to downgrade TensorFlow and says that only versions 2 is available.
here is code and output:

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.2
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

output:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15.2 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15.2
2.9.2
```

I tried this code by creating some new projects in Colab but I got no new results

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade `tensorflow` in `google colab` you must downgrade the version of python because `python3.8` is not compatible with `tensorflow1.x`. So, Downgrade the version of python to `python3.7` and install `tensorflow1.x`. This will work.

1.At first,  Install `python==3.7` version.

```
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.7

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2

#check python version
!python --version
```

2. The above code will install `python3.7` version, but it is not mapped to colab kernel, so we must map newly installed python.

```
# install pip for python==3.7
!sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!python get-pip.py

# install colab dependencies
!python -m pip install ipython ipython_genutils ipykernel jupyter_console prompt_toolkit httplib2 astor

# link to the old google package
!ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google \
       /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google
```

Let's check version of python again, it will be `python==3.7.16`:

```
!python --version
```

3. Now, it's time to install tensorflow 1.x.

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.x
```

I hope that it will help to fix your issue.Thank you!